# How to use a foreach loop to pick required words from an array?

Tags: c#

I want to pick class names of all classes from given input code. However my code is picking just one class name. What should I do?

I am working on a Windows form in C#. I have tried to it do with a `foreach` loop but it is not working

```
private void btnDetect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // splitting code
  string mystr = richTextBox1.Text;
  if (mystr.ToLower().Contains("class"))
  {
    string[] splitText = mystr.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
    foreach (string word in splitText)
    {
      int classindex = Array.FindIndex(splitText, r => r.Contains("class"));
      string className = splitText[classindex + 1];
      MessageBox.Show(className);
    }
  }
  else
    MessageBox.Show("class not found");
  }
}
```

I expect the output to show all the class names in the input, but the output I get is only the first class name

Comment: Can you please post sample input and expected output

Comment: What does the text look like?

Comment: your findindex finds the first... it will always only find the first it will just show you it for each number of "class" it finds..did you not mean to check if word is class, and show the next item in the array instead?

Comment: Show some example **input** text, then we can test and fix your code. Also consider using **String** functions like `indexOf(x)` to find all instances of _"class"_.

Comment: public class Square
{
    public double Side { get; }

    public Square(double side)
    {
        Side = side;
    }
}
public class Circle
{
    public double Radius { get; }

    public Circle(double radius)
    {
        Radius = radius;
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.FindIndex` always returns the first index because the condition never changes.

You could use:

```
string[] tokens = mystr.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<string> classList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (tokens[i].Equals("class", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        classList.Add(tokens[++i]);
}
```

Comment: it returns .. System.Collection.Generic.List'1[System.String]

Answer (score 0):

you could use this method :

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetClasses(string str)
    {
        if (!str.Contains("Class", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) yield break;

        string[] words =str.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        int wordsCount = words.Length;

        for (var index = 0; index < wordsCount; index++)
        {
            string word = words[index];
            if (!word.Equals("Class", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;
            if (wordsCount > index + 1) continue;
            if (words[index + 1].Equals("Class", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) continue;

            yield return words[index + 1];
        }
    }
```